# Radius of gyration and aggregates

Tags: molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry, gromacs

I have performed a MD simulation using GROMACS for a system of 100  caffeine molecules in water. It is expected caffeine  form aggregates.

I have calculated the radius of gyration for the simulation time of 25 ns for the system.

What is the impact/ means this radius of gyration parameter tells on aggregate formation since system contain aggregates in several position inside the simulation box?

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here, and we hope to see much more of you in the future! Sorry for not welcoming you earlier :'(   It looks like you made your account 8 months ago and also were "last seen" 8 months ago, so we'll assume that if the question is answered, you won't even see it, but if you do come back and want the question to be re-opened, just ping me in chat by typing @NikeDattani before your message.

Comment: By Rg, are you calculating the Rg of a single caffeine molecule? 25 ns is too short simulation. Also, aggregation, means the molecules are collapsing, which will result in a smaller Rg value.